# QWidget with own child-widgets (buttons) and background image does not work

Tags: qt, qt5

I want to implement a window in Qt which has

- an background-image I draw for my own out of a QImage
- a normal widget (a QPushButton) at an absolute position

That's the code I have:

```
// the constructor
ReplayWidget::ReplayWidget(QWidget *parent)
             :QWidget(parent, Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint)
{
   m_closeButton = new QPushButton(parent);
   m_closeButton->setText("Close");
   m_closeButton->move(10, 10);
   m_closeButton->setMinimumSize(QSize(100, 51));
   m_closeButton->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding);
}

// the overwritten repaint-method
void ReplayWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* pe)
{
   QPainter painter(this);

   if (m_bgImage)
   {
      painter.drawImage(QPoint(0, 0), *m_bgImage);
   }
   QWidget::paintEvent(pe);
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work, the image from m_bgImage appears as expected but the pushbutton is not visible.

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: @mugiseyebrows yes, that's it - thank you! :-)

Comment: Please convert the comment into an answer and tick it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `m_closeButton->show()` and replace `QPushButton(parent)` with `QPushButton(this)`